# Terraform fails for kubernetes storage class when changing type from gp2 to gp3

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, storage-class-specifier

I have 2 storage class deployed using terraform(storage and expandable-storage). Below is the code for both.

Before

```
resource "kubernetes_storage_class" "expandable-storage" {
  metadata {
    name = "expandable-storage"
  }
  storage_provisioner = "kubernetes.io/aws-ebs"
  reclaim_policy      = "Retain"
  parameters = {
    type = "gp2"
    fsType: "ext4"
    encrypted: "true"
  }
  allow_volume_expansion = true
  volume_binding_mode = "Immediate"
}

resource "kubernetes_storage_class" "storage" {
  metadata {
    name = "storage"
  }
  storage_provisioner = "ebs.csi.aws.com"
  reclaim_policy      = "Retain"
  parameters = {
    type = "gp2"
    fsType: "ext4"
    encrypted: "true"
  }
  allow_volume_expansion = true
  volume_binding_mode = "Immediate"
}

resource "null_resource" "k8s_storage_class_patch" {
  depends_on = [kubernetes_storage_class.expandable-storage]
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "/bin/bash scripts/storage_class_patch.sh"
  }
}
```

After this I tried to update parameter for both storage class from type gp2 to type gp3.

After

```
resource "kubernetes_storage_class" "expandable-storage" {
  metadata {
    name = "expandable-storage"
  }
  storage_provisioner = "kubernetes.io/aws-ebs"
  reclaim_policy      = "Retain"
  parameters = {
    type = "gp3"
    fsType: "ext4"
    encrypted: "true"
  }
  allow_volume_expansion = true
  volume_binding_mode = "Immediate"
}

resource "kubernetes_storage_class" "storage" {
  metadata {
    name = "storage"
  }
  storage_provisioner = "ebs.csi.aws.com"
  reclaim_policy      = "Retain"
  parameters = {
    type = "gp3"
    fsType: "ext4"
    encrypted: "true"
  }
  allow_volume_expansion = true
  volume_binding_mode = "Immediate"
}

resource "null_resource" "k8s_storage_class_patch" {
  depends_on = [kubernetes_storage_class.expandable-storage]
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "/bin/bash scripts/storage_class_patch.sh"
  }
}
```

After applying the resource module "storage" updated to gp3 but for "expandable-storage" module I am getting error

```
Error: storageclasses.storage.k8s.io "expandable-storage" already exists
```

I am not sure what is causing this as same changes worked for other storage class.

Comment: Well, it says that object already exists in the cluster. If you list the storageclass objects, is there already an `expandable-storage` object?

Comment: Also, you might want to consider moving to `v1` resources: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/kubernetes/latest/docs/resources/storage_class_v1.

Comment: @MarkoE Yes, like I said, both resource `storage` and `expandable-storage` already present with type = gp2. I updated type to gp3 for both. Resource `storage` got updated to gp3 without error but the same change for `expandable-storage` gives me error for "already exists".

Comment: But the code you posted shows `gp2` for both or am I missing something?

Comment: Code posted is how I deployed first time and later I just changed `gp2 -> gp3` for both did `terraform apply` again. `storage` got updated to gp2 and `expandable-storage` got failed due above mentioned reason. I think it has got to do something with that `null_resource` in our code.

Comment: It probably is.